# Difference between storing data as a key and as property of a hash object

Tags: redis

Right now, I'm storing user objects as follows:

```
user1 = ( id: 1, name: "bob")
user2 = { id: 2, name: "steve"}

HMSET "user:1", user1
HMSET "user:2", user2

HGETALL "user:1" would return the user1 object
HGETALL "user:2" would return the user2 object
```

I'm wondering if there would be any significant difference (performance or other) if I did:

```
user1 = ( id: 1, name: "bob")
user2 = { id: 2, name: "steve"}

HSET "USER", 1, JSON.stringify(user1)
HSET "USER", 2, JSON.stringify(user2)

HGET "USER", 1 would give me the string representation of user1 object
HGET "USER", 2 woudl give me the string representation of user2 object
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a huge difference either way.  It's mostly going to boil down to a design decision based on what you're doing, although whichever you use you should stay consistent throughout the project to avoid confusion.

Here are some pros to method 2:

- using JSON could help maintain type consistency
- Redis will use less memory and may be a tiny bit faster, since it doesn't have to store or lookup those extra keys
- might be easier to think about and work with in code

The main negative for method 2 is summed up in the following example.  Say you need to update a user's name.  Here's how you would do it with each method.

```
 // Method 1:
 HMSET user:1 name newname

 // Method 2:
 result = JSON.parse(HGET user 1)
 result.name = newname
 HSET user 1 JSON.stringify(result)
```